# Circuit to invert logic of enable pin on IC

Tags: analog, dc-dc-converter, buck

I have an LM2596 DC-DC buck converter which has an enable pin that enables the IC when the voltage on it is lower than 1.4 V and disables it once voltage goes above 1.4 V.

Is it possible to create a circuit to invert this logic? So below 1.4 V the IC is disabled, and above that it is enabled.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it would help to show us a schematic to help you decide how to implement the inversion.

Comment: I don't have a schematic on hand as I'm trying to implement this in an e scooter main board as a replacement to an old burned out smd regulator that had the enable logic inverted

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 1.4V? Or is it just logic high and low? What is the input voltage? By replacing, do you just mean soldering where the old one was or creating a new circuit board? Do you have access to the input voltage?

Comment: Yes it has to be exactly 1.4v, I bought a PCB that handles the dcdc step down which uses the lm2596 I simply lifted up the enable pin so that I could  tap it. I have to use a resistor divider to drop from the 33~42v of the battery to 3.3v and then use that to power this circuit, I was thinking of using an inverting op amp maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHSDa5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the input is >1.4V, ENABLE is 0V which would enable the IC. If the input is <1.4V, ENABLE is 2.8V which would disable the IC.

Some notes:

The 2.8V LDO could be a higher voltage and then you could use a voltage divider to get 2.8V.

If you are obtaining 3.3V from a voltage divider, you could increase it to comfortably fit the LDO's dropout voltage.